# How to reliably schedule events in Corda?

Tags: corda

Many examples of using event scheduling in Corda -- including it's own reference implementation of the Interest Rate Swap contract -- rely on `SchedulableState` mechanism. Unfortunately there is not much information available in the Corda documentation regarding the use of the scheduler in a real business context. Reliable execution of scheduled business events is important, and, as a party who depends on a CorDapp to automatically trigger scheduled events in order to fulfil my contractual obligations, I'd like to implement robust controls for whether things that had been scheduled have actually run. For example, it is possible to envisage a situation whereby a scheduled flow kicked off, but then ended prematurely due to a bug in the code or node misconfiguration without achieving its indented purpose. The question therefore is what CorDapp designer and/or node operator could do to ensure reliable execution of scheduled activities?

Answer (score 0):

`SchedulableState` normally is used to represent recurring events.

Please check out this HeartBeat sample: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/heartbeat

You can think of monthly payment or a paycheck that is reoccured every month.